# how to perform event specific to a certain MKAnnotation

Tags: ios4, core-location, mkannotation, mapkit

i have an map that has a few hundred MKPointAnnotations and have been set up to have a left and right callout accessory, the issue i am having is finding a way to perform an action that is specific to that annotation

for example if someone presses a specific annotation i want to go to a new viewController that has detailed information about were the annotation is. I have setup a custom object that conforms to the MKAnnotation so all the data is contained into the annotation as such...

```
    @synthesize coordinate;
@synthesize _title;
@synthesize _date;
@synthesize _description;
@synthesize _coordinates;

- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
    theCoordinate.latitude = _coordinates.latitude;
    theCoordinate.longitude = _coordinates.longitude;
    return theCoordinate; 
}

- (NSString *)title {
 return _title;
}

- (NSString *)subtitle {
 return _description;
}

- (void)dealloc {
 [super dealloc];
 [_description release];
 [_date release];
 [_title release];
}
```

can anyone help me with this please :D

Answer (score 3):

Let us consider the class name your code given above is annotation.m

In your viewController

```
annotation  *annotationObject=[[annotation alloc]init];
annotationObject.title=@"Some title";
annotationObject.subTitle=@"Some subtitle";
annotationObject.coordinate=someCoordinate;
[mapView addAnnotation:annotationObject];
[annotationObject release];
```

Put the above code in a loop to add many annotations, or put the annotaion objects in a array and use addAnnotations to mapView.

In viewForAnnotation add a accessory button to the annotation

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
 MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"Pin"] autorelease];
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    UIButton *annotationButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = annotationButton;
    return annotationView;
}
```

When user selects the acessory button this delegate will be called

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
     //Get the specific annotation by the view.annotation.title 
     //Go to another view that has details
}
```

Comment: ok that makes sense, and thanks for the reply but i cannot access other information within the custom annotation as mentioned above such as description only title, subtitle and coordinate?

Comment: FYI subtitle is the description.. Are you saying that you are not able access annotation subtitles and coordinates. But you are able to access annotation title alone.